# What is the meaning of the line "Upon a homely object Love can wink" in this context

Tags: poetry

What's the meaning of the last line of this extract from Shakespeare's *Two Gentlemen of Verona*?

> *Valentine.* This is the gentleman I told your ladyship
>   Had come along with me, but that his mistress
>   Did hold his eyes lock'd in her crystal looks.
>
> *Silvia.* Belike that now she hath enfranchised them
>   Upon some other pawn for fealty.
>
> *Valentine.* Nay, sure, I think she holds them prisoners still.
>
> *Silvia.* Nay, then he should be blind; and, being blind
>   How could he see his way to seek out you?
>
> *Valentine.* Why, lady, Love hath twenty pair of eyes.
>
> *Thurio.* They say that Love hath not an eye at all.
>
> *Valentine.* To see such lovers, Thurio, as yourself:
>   ***Upon a homely object Love can wink***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Wink* here has the sense *close the eyes* - the same sense is in play when we say that an authority *winks at* a violation of some regulation, pretends not to see it.

To paraphrase this very "conceited" dialogue in More or Less Fully Modern English:

> Valentine:  Love has twenty pairs of eyes.
>   Thurio:   What I've always heard is that Love has no eyes at all.
>   Valentine:  Well, of course when it looks at you; ***Love can close its eyes when
>
>          it sees something ugly.***

Comment: I've always heard that [love is **blind**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22love+is+blind%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but I think it's Off Topic Lit Crit anyway.

Comment: I recognise the phrase _wink at_ with the sense you give, from 19th century writers such as W S Gilbert, but I would regard it as obsolete. I know the OED doesn't mark it as such, but that entry hasn't been updated since 1926.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this is just asking for literal meaning, not a critical interpretation; the fact that it appears in a stage work (not a literary work!) is incidental.

Comment: @ColinFine 2012: "While the administration winks at the Muslim Brotherhood and prostrates itself before Islamist audiences, Obama lamely claims that his detractors are wrong..." -[Accuracy in Media](http://www.aim.org/guest-column/its-not-just-obamas-lies-its-the-premise-of-obamas-lies/),"Students will get demerits for dust on their desks or a skirt that rides up when they kneel down, but the administration winks at them joyriding 20 mph over the speed limit and rolling through stop signs." -[Stuff Fundies Like](http://www.stufffundieslike.com/2012/12/commandments-concerning-motor-vehicles)

Comment: Did "homely" mean "ugly" in Shakespearean England?

Comment: @User58220  Yes, one of its meanings is "unbeautiful"; it is often contrasted with "beautiful" or "comely": *I'll have thy beauty scratch'd with briers, and made / More homely than thy state.* -*WT*, IV,4  *Hath homely age the alluring beauty took / 
From my poor cheek?* -*CE*, II, 1

Comment: @User58220: It *still* means "plain, ugly" in many if not most usages.

Comment: Well, *British Self-Taught: With Comments in American* Norman W. Schur, 1973, says current British usage of "homely" is "simple, unpretentious, nothing fancy", and corresponds to the North American "homey".

Comment: @StoneyB: both those examples of _winks at_ I would have interpreted in the sense of _winks one eye to indicate a shared understanding, hidden from others_. (The OED says  To convey (a message) by means of a wink of the eye"). But you may be right.

Comment: @ColinFine You have access to a later OED than I. [*OED 1*, s.v. **Wink**](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio102murruoft#page/176/mode/2up) has a very old (1100) and ***Obs.*** "give a significant glance to" (sense 7); finds "close one eye momentarily, in a flippant or frivolous manner, esp. to convey intimate information"  (sense 8) first recorded in 1837; and glosses *wink at* as "to 'shut one's eyes to' (an offence, fault, defect, impropriety, or irregularity); to connive at." But I have no doubt that many or even most people today understand the phrase in your sense.

Comment: @StoneyB: yes, that's a "1993 Draft addition" in the online OED. I'd previously noticed sense 8, but this fits better.